# Import ES6 module elements directly or destructure const assignment following the import?

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, destructuring, es6-modules

Somewhat new to ES6 modules and find myself torn between the following 2 patterns...

Pattern #1 - Destructuring on `import`

```
import { func1, func2, func3 } from 'my-funcs';
```

Pattern #2 - Destructuring on `const`

```
import * as myFuncs from 'my-funcs'; 
const { func1, func2, func3 } = myFuncs;
```

I like the pattern #1 for its brevity, but I also like pattern #2 as it seems more explicit.

Are there good reasons to use one over the other?

Comment: Using Pattern #1 would benefit from [tree-shaking](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html) optimization while Pattern #2 would not

Comment: thanks @RobM.!  I wondered if such optimization existed (and of course it does).  Just the kind of information I was looking for.  :)

Answer (score 3):

In ES6, an import is bound to a variable (as opposed to a value). This means that if the exporting module changes the variable it exported, that updated value will be reflected across all modules that imported it.

For example, suppose we have a module which exports a primitive value and then changes it after some unspecified period of time.

myVar.js

```
export var myVar = "1";
setTimeout(() => {myVar = "2"}, 2000);
```

Suppose you imported it like so:

main1.js

```
import { myVar } from './myVar.js';
console.log(myVar);
setTimeout(() => { console.log(myVar); }, 3000);
```

The output would be:

```
1
2
```

However, if you assigned the original value to a variable immediately upon importing it, then the value would be unchanged.

main2.js

```
import * as MyVar from './myVar.js';
const myVar = MyVar.myVar;
console.log(myVar);
setTimeout(() => { console.log(myVar); }, 3000);
```

The output of this program would be:

```
1
1
```

This difference may be something you want to keep in mind.

Comment: Excellent information!  You've got me leaning toward pattern #1...seems like pattern #2 could lead to unexpected outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is not destructuring, it's importing named exports into the module scope. The second one does import the module namespace object under the name `myFuncs` and then destructures it.

The major difference is that in the second pattern you've got constants, not direct references to the exported bindings (which might change). This is important e.g. for circular dependencies.

A minor difference is the additional identifier `myFuncs`, which is rather useless. It does however give you access to all exports of the module, which is important for tree-shaking - if you explicitly import only parts of a module, a bundler might produce smaller results.

> Are there good reasons to use one over the other?

Absolutely - the first pattern is simpler, shorter, works correctly in edge cases, and can be better optimised.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi.  Could you explain how not having a direct reference to the exported bindings is relevant to circular dependencies?

Comment: With circular dependencies, the module you are importing might not yet have been evaluated. That is not a problem if you use the imports later (e.g. in a function that is called somewhere else), it is a problem when you do `const { func1, func2, func3 } = myFuncs;` while `myFuncs` does not yet contain the values.