# Different ways of writing module imports

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What is the difference exactly between the following 2 ways of writing import statements ?

```
// 1st
import Ember from 'ember';
const { Route } = Ember;

// 2nd
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
```

Is it like the 2nd way is more efficient or is there something more to it ?

Comment: Obviously they're importing different things, so what do you mean by "more efficient"?

Comment: @Bergi actually its the same thing.

Comment: @Lux Only since the edit, which seems to make it a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39238697/1048572)

Comment: not a duplicate. Its literally only the same because ember dicided that it should be the same. But yes, only since the edit. Sorry @Bergi

Answer (score 4):

Yes, 2nd way is more efficient - you import only needed parts of framework. [Complete list of reasons behind this change in Ember](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0176-javascript-module-api.md)

Answer (score 0):

It should be mentioned that depending on your ember version they are 100% identical. However *always use the second way*!

The first one are the *old* imports. The second one is the new Ember module API.
Ember introduced this very early, so people can start using it. At build time they transformed it to the old version. This allowed people to switch to the new import style as soon as possible.

However over time the second way will get benefits that the first cant get. And some day the first version will be deprecated, and even removed.